# How to pass utm parameter to another url on redirect using elementor form and how to strip the same parameters if there is not value in URL

Tags: wordpress, parameters, elementor

I have create 3 hidden form field in a elementor form and store the utm parameters value in hidden field using dynamic request GET parameters and redirected it to the another domain with same parameters

Redirected URL set in elementor form:
[https://app.simply.coach/signup?utm_source=[field](https://app.simply.coach/signup?utm_source=%5Bfield) id="utm_source"]&medium=[field id="medium"]&gclid=[field id="gclid"]

If the users lands from google ads the sample url look like
https://mmag.co.in/coaching-software-comparison/coachaccountable-alternative/?utm_source=Exact_Simply_Coach_Exact&medium=SC_Brand_Campaign&gclid=CjwKCAiA85efBhBbEiwAD7oLQDIG63KlJ3ZpybXk8Zjl7sOeojYmAbDqXpr8mHeqNahl5v-TMBpMPRoCeVkQAvD_BwE

and after submitt the form it redirects to https://app.simply.coach/signup with same parameters.

But the problems is if organic users lands on
https://mmag.co.in/coaching-software-comparison/coachaccountable-alternative

then on redirect the the url https://app.simply.coach/signup?utm_source=&medium=&gclid=
how can i strip the parameters in the redirect url if the value is empty.

The code to save the parameters in cookie

```
// Check if the UTM parameters are present in the URL
if (isset($_GET['utm_source']) || isset($_GET['medium']) || isset($_GET['gclid'])) {
    // Set the UTM parameters as cookies
    setcookie('utm_source', $_GET['utm_source'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    setcookie('utm_medium', $_GET['medium'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    setcookie('gclid', $_GET['gclid'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}

// Check if the UTM parameters are set as cookies
if (isset($_COOKIE['utm_source']) || isset($_COOKIE['medium']) || isset($_COOKIE['gclid'])) {
    // Get the UTM parameters from the cookies
    $utm_source = $_COOKIE['utm_source'];
    $utm_medium = $_COOKIE['medium'];
    $gclid = $_COOKIE['gclid'];
} else {
    // If the UTM parameters are not set as cookies, set them as empty strings
    $utm_source = '';
    $utm_medium = '';
    $gclid = '';
}
```